# What relative functionality needs to be implemented when users click an "Accept Cookies" button?

Tags: privacy, cookies, logging

As of 2018, a recent security measure was passed, called 'The Cookie Law'.

It states that; if you have a website or blog with visitors from the EU (which is likely to happen), "you need a cookie warning or popup notice when collecting user data by means of cookies", thus requiring need to get consent for doing so from the user(s).

It seems that - once accepted - a cookie would simply be placed on the client's device, preventing the request for consent to be displayed again.

However, there are paid services that log those consents, as well.

What should be logged, and is there an example of such a log, so I can apply those records (or similar data) to the functionality of my accepted requests?

Comment: This is not a security question. This is both a regulatory/legal question and a programming question.